# How to recompile firefox 57 debian package using debuild?

Tags: apt, firefox, compiling, deb

I am trying to recompile firefox 57 (the goal is to add a couple of patches) in Ubuntu 16.04.

I am performing the usual procedure:

```
sudo apt-get source firefox
sudo apt-get build-dep firefox
cd firefox-57.0.1+build2/
debuild -us -uc
```

On the build-dep stage I get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 builddeps:firefox : Depends: cargo (>= 0.20)
                     Depends: rustc (>= 1.19.0)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have all standard repositories for xenial (including `universe`, `multivers`), and there are no such packages. The latest `rustc` has version 1.17.

I tried:

1. Installing fresh rustc & cargo locally and passing it's path to debuild via `--prepend-path`
2. Installing rustc & cargo globaly using `ppa:jonathonf/rustlang`.
3. Installing rustc, cargo & clang/llvm from ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa.

But I get a compilation errors:

```
/home/idavydov/src/ff/firefox-57.0.1+build2/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/dist/include/mozilla/Compiler.h:49:12: fatal error: 'cstddef' file not found, err: true
/home/idavydov/src/ff/firefox-57.0.1+build2/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/dist/include/mozilla/mozalloc.h:16:12: fatal error: 'new' file not found, err: true
/home/idavydov/src/ff/firefox-57.0.1+build2/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/dist/include/mozilla/mozalloc.h:16:12: fatal error: 'new' file not found, err: true
...
    stack backtrace:
       0:     0x5584a7075fb3 - std::sys::imp::backtrace::tracing::imp::unwind_backtrace::h8ed7485deb8ab958
                                   at /checkout/src/libstd/sys/unix/backtrace/tracing/gcc_s.rs:49
       1:     0x5584a7072520 - std::sys_common::backtrace::_print::h3d4f9ea58578e60f
                                   at /checkout/src/libstd/sys_common/backtrace.rs:69
...
      11:     0x5584a707aa9b - std::sys::imp::thread::Thread::new::thread_start::hbaf1b5aa1ca8e3ea
                                   at /checkout/src/liballoc/boxed.rs:736
                                   at /checkout/src/libstd/sys_common/thread.rs:24
                                   at /checkout/src/libstd/sys/unix/thread.rs:90
      12:     0x2b1467a296b9 - start_thread
      13:     0x2b1467f5c3dc - clone
      14:                0x0 - <unknown>
```

**What kind of compilation environment is required to rebuild firefox 57 deb in ubuntu xenial?**

Comment: I think you simply need to run `sudo apt-get build-dep firefox` before compilation. But it does not work.

Comment: @N0rbert, yes, that what's I did when I got a builddep error. Adding mozilla ppa helps with builddep, but still I get compilation errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this. There were two problems:

**No packages for build-dep**

For that the correct way was to add the relevant ppa:

```
sudo apt-get source firefox
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get build-dep firefox
cd firefox-57.0.1+build2/
debuild -uc -us -b
```

**Compilation error**

This was most likely related to the available free space on disk. Firefox [requires](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Simple_Firefox_build/Linux_and_MacOS_build_preparation) 30GB of free space and at least 2GB of RAM to compile. I tried on another machine with a lot of resources, and it worked fine.